# Prototype executing without ever being called?

Tags: javascript, prototype, breadth-first-search

I am looking at code for a BFS and I dont understand why the prototype toString is being executed. Look below. Without this line, each node is return as an object. Please help me understand what is going on with that prototype function. Thank You!

```
  function Node(info){

       this.info = info
       this.left = null;
       this.right = null;
       this.level = null; 
   }

   Node.prototype.toString = function() {
       console.log(this.info);
       console.log("activate"); 
       return this.info;

   }  

   function BFT(node) {

        node.level = 1;

        var queue = [node];

        var output = [];

        var current_level = node.level;

            while(queue.length > 0) {

                  current_node = queue.shift(); 
               console.log("before");
                  if(current_node.level > current_level) {
                console.log("?")
                         current_level++;
                         output.push("\n");

                  }  

                  output.push(current_node + " ");

                  if(current_node.left) {
                       current_node.left.level = current_level + 1; 
                       queue.push(current_node.left); 
                  }  

                  if(current_node.right) {
                       current_node.right.level = current_level + 1; 
                       queue.push(current_node.right); 
                  }  

            }

         return output.join("") 
   }



   var root = new Node(9);
       root.left = new Node(8);    
       root.right = new Node(7);

       root.left.left = new Node(2);
       root.left.right = new Node(4);

       root.right.left = new Node(6);
       root.right.right = new Node(8);

       root.left.left.left = new Node('a');
       root.left.left.right = new Node('b');

       root.left.right.right = new Node('c');

       console.log(BFT(root))
```

Comment: `console.log` calls it to get a string representation of the thing it's trying to print out.

Comment: *When* is it being executed? What do you expect `current_node + " "` to do?

Comment: its being executed between the console.log("before") and console.log("?") that I added

Comment: my question is what is triggering the prototype to return the value

Comment: as @nnnnn was trying to point out - the line `output.push(current_node + " ");` is the culprit - ignore when it's being logged to console. `current_node + " "` coerces current_node to a string, hence the call to toString